# Use a shortest-paths argument to prove a combinatorics identity

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, combinatorial-proofs

Let m and n be nonnegative integers, and let r, s, and t be nonnegative integers such that $r + s + t = m$. Use a shortest-paths argument to prove that:
$$\binom{m+n}{n}=\sum_{a,b,c} \binom{r+a}{a}\binom{s+b}{b}\binom{t+c}{c}$$

Comment: Presumably $a+b+c=n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This graphical representation of a typical staircase pattern in a  $n \times m$ rectangle:

[image]

shows 3 boxes, here represented in red, black, blue, the nature of which we are going to explain using natural coordinates conventions.

How are these boxes determined ? By the fact that each staircase pattern reaches the first level at $y=r$ for a certain $x=a$; in the same way, level $y=r+s$ is reached for a certain $x=a+b$, giving intermediate points with coordinates

$$(a,r), \ \ (a+b,r+s)\ $$

(otherwise said, $a$ is determined by $r$, $b$ is determined by $s$...)

Together with endpoints with coordinates $(0,0), (n,m)$, we have all the diagonal "corners" of the 3 boxes attached to the staircase pattern.

Let us now partition the set of staircase patterns into classes $C_{a,b}$ **having the same 3 boxes**. Each such class being composed of the concatenation of any staircase pattern in the different boxes, we are in a multiplicative context and

$$Card(C_{a,b})=\binom{r+a}{a}\binom{s+b}{b}\binom{t+c}{c}$$

elements. As it is a partition, it remains to sum all these products to get the total number $\binom{m+n}{n}$ of staircase patterns.

Comment: nice and well explained answer (+1)

Comment: @G Cab Hi! Thanks for the compliment. Besides, how is the 2nd COVID wave in Italy? In France, it's taking a huge size, and no drastic measures are really taken...

Comment: Hi to you Jean Marie, yes unfortunately I heard about 2nd wave in France, pls. be more careful than before. I am leaving in a small city that became a "red zone" at the very beginning, the containment was drastic but very effective and no much problems now (for the moment..). I would like to exchange some words, now is late, but tomorrow I will invite you in chat. Take care.

Comment: @G.Cab Thanks for your answer. OK for a chat today.

Comment: Hi Jean Marie, I opened [this chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113496/gcab) if you are free we can talk a bit

Answer (score 0):

Recall that you can interpret ${n + k\choose n}$ as the number of lattice paths from $(0, 0)$ to $(n, k)$ while only moving north or east. In addition, each of these ${n + k\choose n}$ paths are all *shortest paths* because we always move one unit closer to the destination. Also, you need to use the fact that subpaths of shortest paths are also shortest paths (otherwise, we could just take a shorter subpath to make the entire shortest path even shorter).

Now interpret ${m+n\choose n}$ as the number of shortest paths from $(0, 0)$ to $(m, n)$ while moving only north or east. Interpret the three terms in the sum as subpaths of the shortest path.